# How can I create a dictionary in python from a txt file?

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

I have a file that looks like this:

```
NODE=SC-1,CPU=90
NODE=SC-1,MEM=10
NODE=SC-1,FS=80
NODE=SC-1,DIORead=30
NODE=SC-1,DIOWrite=40
NODE=SC-1,NTX=30
NODE=SC-1,NRX=40
NODE=SC-2,CPU=80
NODE=SC-2,MEM=10
NODE=SC-2,FS=80
NODE=SC-2,DIORead=30
NODE=SC-2,DIOWrite=40
NODE=SC-2,NTX=30
NODE=SC-2,NRX=40
```

How can I parse the file and create a dictionary for node SC-1 and one for node SC-2 that I can later in my program refer to to get specific values for specific nodes?

Comment: Is the file structure fixed? I mean, is the line structure inside the file always of the form ``NODE=<nodename>,<param>=<value>``?

Comment: First off, it's allways a good idea to include snippets of stuff you tried. Second: Could you provide us with a sample of what the dictionary should look like?

Comment: @Powertieke I'm looking to get something like this:
print sc-1.items()  ##  [('CPU', '90'), ('MEM', '10'), ('FS', '80')]
print sc-2.items()  ##  [('CPU', '80'), ('MEM', '10'), ('FS', '80')]
I committed the rest of the keys for convenience. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(dict)
for line in open('input_file','r'):
    line = line.strip()
    a,b = line.split(',')
    node = a.split('=')[1] 
    key, value = b.split('=')
    d[node][key] = value
```

Comment: defaultdict is the clear winner here, +1! The values all appear to be ints - if the OP concurs, then you could do the string-to-int conversion here too.  Or just do `d[node][key] = int(value)` in a try block, and on exception, just store the value as a string.

Comment: Thanks Paul, but are we creating separate dictionaries for each node?

Comment: @dan in this code, yes, but they are inside `d` keyed by their node name.

Comment: I didn't know about ``defaultdict`` yet, awesome. Thanks for this.

Comment: @DanD Thanks a lot! now, how can access keys for a particular node if the above code is used to build the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to parse this file & keep all `SC-*` as keys and the rest of the stuff as their values. If the keys are duplicates, then merge the values. If this is what you are looking for, then i have hand-written some code which does exactly that -

I split the line first on `,` then on `=` & get the key, if key already there then merge else create a new entry.

```
def readFileIntoDict(fileHandle, dictName):
     line = fileHandle.readline() 
     dictName = {} 

     while line: 
         key  = line.split(',').split('=')[1]
         if key in dictName:
             dictName[key].append(line)
         else:
             dictName[key] = [line]
         line = fileHandle.readline() 
     return dictName
```

Correct me if i have interpreted what you want.

Comment: If you find yourself writing "if key in dictvar, add key to current node, else initialize new node", it is a good sign that a defaultdict would clean things up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my try (untested):

```
sc1 = {}    
sc2 = {}    
f = open("myfile", "r")
for line in f:  
  dict = None
  for statement in line.split(','):
    varname, value = statement.split('=')
    if varname == 'NODE' and value == 'SC-1':
      dict = sc1
    elif varname == 'NODE' and value == 'SC-2':
      dict = sc2
    else:
      dict[varname] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "2D" dictionary, i.e. a dictionary of dictionaries.

The keys of the "outer" dictionary will be the node names (e.g. 'SC-1', 'SC-2'), and the value will be another dictionary with keys {CPU, MEM, FS, DIORead, DIOWrite, NTX, NRX}.

like this:

```
outerDict = {}
for line in open('input', 'rb').readlines():
    key = line.split(',')[0].split('=')[0]
    key2, val = line.split(',')[1].split('=')

    if outerDict.has_key(key):
        outerDict[key][key2] = val
    else:
        outerDict[key] = {}
        outerDict[key][key2] = val
```

Comment: "has_key" is old-style Python, deprecated now in favor of "if key in dict". Unfortunately, there are still tutorials lying around that teach it.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your file structure is consistent with your example above, this is what I'd do -

```
import pprint

def read_file_into_dict(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')

    main_dict = {}

    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        node_line, param_line = line.split(',')
        node_name = node_line.split('=')[1]
        param, value = param_line.split('=')

        if main_dict.get(node_name):
            main_dict[node_name][param] = value
        else:
            main_dict[node_name] = {param: value}

    return main_dict

pprint.pprint(read_file_into_dict('sample.txt'))
```

Here's the output -

```
$ python sample.py 
{'SC-1': {'CPU': '90',
          'DIORead': '30',
          'DIOWrite': '40',
          'FS': '80',
          'MEM': '10',
          'NRX': '40',
          'NTX': '30'},
 'SC-2': {'CPU': '80',
          'DIORead': '30',
          'DIOWrite': '40',
          'FS': '80',
          'MEM': '10',
          'NRX': '40',
          'NTX': '30'}}
```